# How to equalize <return> and <kb-enter> in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Some key bindings are designed in a way that Enter (`<return>`) and numpad Enter (`<kb-enter>`) are not the same (I guess, if a binding is `(kbd "<return>/<kb-enter>")` not `(kbd "RET")`). Is it possible to rewrite `<kb-enter` to `<return>` in Emacs or I have to change system settings?

Comment: When I hit numpad Enter is says `RET (translated from <kp-enter>)`  so it gives the same key as Return and apparently there is some mechanism that does the translating between the two. Doesn't it work the same for you?

Comment: @Tom, yes, it is the same *after* the translation. But some extensions define keybindings explicitly (`kp-enter` or `return`), and thus the function, bound to this explicit keybinding, simply does not work with another type of `RET`. That's a theory, though. I've noted the distinction empirically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want:

```
(define-key local-function-key-map [kp-enter] [return])
```

That will translate the `<kp-enter>` key to the `<return>` key.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it, but some functionality has been lost with such `define-key`. For example, `newline` command linked to `return` does not work when `kp-enter` is pressed (`<return> is undefined` error), i.e. *some* functions that the `return` has weren't passed to the `kp-enter`. It there any way to rewrite this `define-key` so it got the full functionality of the `return`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but keep in mind that your keyboard Return key might correspond to the `<return>` function key, or it might correspond to ASCII `RET` (aka Control-M).  And when the binding of the key (whatever it is) inserts a newline char, that is from the command it is bound to. A newline char is actually Control-J, and in some modes you need to hit `C-j` to insert a newline char. Dunno whether it will help, but try adding this one also: `(define-key local-function-key-map [kp-enter] [(control ?m)])`